# What is the special die with pictograms in Monopoly used for?

Tags: monopoly, dice

I think that I have a pretty standard version Monopoly, which looks exactly like I see in the Web

[image]

It has two white dice with values 1 to 6 and one red with values 1,2,3 and 3 pictures. I haven't seen any rules that say what to do with this second die.

**update** Once, I've got to know that this is called at "speed die", I have managed to find a nice picture of it:

[image: Monopoly Speed Die] [image: speed die]

(The second picture has red regular dice instead of white like I have, but the special die is clearer.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It appears you have the [Championship Edition](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/57702/monopoly-family-game-night-championship-edition) (or the Mega Edition or some other recent modified version), which includes a "speed die" (that third die) for speeding up the game, though it's definitely not part of the original game. There are two "bus" faces, and one "Mr. Monopoly" face.

I found [these rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf) on Hasbro's site explaining how it works. The PDF was was reluctant to load for me, so I've quoted them here:

> 1. When starting the game, hand out an extra $1,000 to each player 
>      (two $500s should work). The game moves fast and you'll need 
>      the extra cash to buy and build.
> 2. Do not use the Speed Die until you've landed on or passed over GO for the first time. Once you collect that first $200 salary, you'll use the Speed Die for the rest of the game. This means that some players will start using the die before others.
> 3. Once you start using the Speed Die, roll it along with the two 
>      white dice on your turn. Then do the following depending on 
>      what you rolled.
>
>    - 1, 2, or 3: Add this number to the roll of the two white dice. You'll zoom around the board.
>    - Bus: This lets you "get off the bus early." Look at the two white dice. You can move the value of one die, the other die, or the sum of both dice. So if you rolled a 1 and a 5, you can move 1 space, 5 spaces, or 6 spaces: it's your choice.
>    - Mr. Monopoly: First, move the sum of the two white dice 
>        and resolve the space you land on (such as drawing a card, 
>        buying the property, paying rent, etc.). Then, one of two 
>        things will happen depending on whether or not there is still 
>        property in the bank.
>
>      YES, there is property in the bank -- Advance to the NEXT 
>        property that the bank still holds and buy it if you wish. If you 
>        don't want to buy this property, move to the space anyway 
>        and put the property up for auction.
>
>      NO, there are no more properties in the bank -- Advance to the 
>        NEXT property on which you will owe another player money.
>
> A few minor details:
>
> - Only the white dice are used when determining if you rolled doubles. Do not look at the Speed Die.
> - If you roll a three-of-a-kind (all of the dice show the same number), 
>     you can move anywhere you want on the board!
> - If you get sent to jail during your move (either by landing on the "Go 
>     to Jail" space or by rolling doubles three times in a row) then your turn 
>     is over and you do not get to use the Speed Die for that turn.
> - Use the white dice ONLY when rolling to get out of jail.
> - Use the sum of all three dice when determining how much to pay on a utility. Note: The Bus and Mr. Monopoly are valued at 0.

Comment: Thanks, Wikipedia also has an entry on it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_%28game%29#Speed_Die. I see now.

Comment: @ire_and_curses News to me too! I also learned that there is competitive Monopoly, and [Hasbro apparently forced them](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10688159#10688159) to use the speed die as a marketing thing, because someone was making a documentary!

Comment: this was in the documentary, [Under The Boardwalk](http://www.monopolydocumentary.com), too :)

Comment: *"property that the bank still holds"* = 'unowned property'

Answer (score 1):

The die is known as the speed die

[@Cascabel's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12682/9999) has the rules from the championship edition for this die.

Mega Edition has different rules (especially surrounding the bus symbol).  The mega edition rules are compatible with a regular monopoly set if you add 16 bus tickets.  To make your own, you need 13 regular ones and 3 that say "all other tickets expire"; the two types of bus tickets should be indistinguishable when face-down.  You could just use playing cards (taking 13 diamonds to be regular bus tickets and 3 spades to be the "all other tickets expire" tickets).  Those rules are included below.

Regardless of which edition you are using, the speed die does make the game shorter, both in making properties get bought faster then in causing players to go bankrupt faster.  It does also somewhat radically change late-game strategy due to the behavior of the Mr. Monopoly symbol once all properties are bought (move to the next property where you owe rent).  This rule allows a player to augment the likelyhood of other players landing on a heavily developed property by buying a contiguous block of the preceding properties and mortgaging them all (thus making the developed one the next place another player would owe rent for a large chunk of the board).  This also increases the value of railroads and utilities as potential "spoilers" in these runs of mortgaged properties.

Mega Edition Rules:

> THE DICE & HOW TO MOVE
>
> On your turn, roll all THREE dice: the two white dice plus the new
>   SPEED DIE.
>
> • If pips appear on all three dice, simply move the total of all
>   three.
>
> • If you roll a Mr. Monopoly, you get a bonus move.  First, move
>   according to the white dice, do what you would normally do on that
>   space; then move again to the next unowned property, which you may now
>   buy.  If you roll a Mr. Monopoly after all of the properties are
>   owned, make a normal move according to the white dice, then move ahead
>   to the first property on which you need to pay rent. If all other
>   players properties are mortgaged, stay where you are.Note: An opponent
>   can’t build or trade until your Mr. Monopoly move is completed.
>
> • If you roll the Bus, first make a normal move according to the white
>   dice, then decide to either take a BUS TICKET for later use(usually a
>   good idea if any tickets are left in the deck) or move again to the
>   nearest Chance/Community Chest space in front of your token
>
> DOUBLES & TRIPLES
>
> Refer  only  to  the  white  dice  when  determining  doubles.  If
>   doubles entitle you to roll again, you may use a Bus Ticket in place
>   of rolling the dice. While in JAIL, roll only the two white dice (if
>   you pay beforehand to get out, roll all three dice).  If you roll
>   TRIPLE 1’s, 2’s, or 3’s, move ahead to ANY space on the board.  Do not
>   roll again.  You do not go to Jail if you’ve rolled doubles twice
>   before rolling triples.
>
> BUS TICKETS
>
> On  any  turn,  you  may  choose to use a Bus Ticket (if you have any)
>   instead of rolling the dice.  If so,  move  forward  to  any space on
>   the same side of the board.    (Corners  are  the final space  on 
>   each  side,  as  well  as  the  first space  of  the  next side.) 
>   After using a Bus Ticket, give the Ticket to the Banker,it is out of
>   play for the remainder of the game.  (There are 16 tickets in all.
>   When they are gone, they’re gone!) Watch out!  When an “All Tickets
>   Expire” card is drawn, all other Tickets in the hands of the players
>   are lost to the  bank  (they’ve expired).  If  a Bus Ticket or Mr.
>   Monopoly  roll causes you to pass GO, collect $200 as usual.  Note:
>   All Bus Tickets should be revealed as collected and kept face up.